# Часть речи "словно"

Tags: части-речи

Watch звучит словно "Вах".
Watch звучит словно у эскимосов.
Pick звучит словно в Покемонвилле.

Является ли в данных предложениях слово "словно" частицей или союзом — и обособляется?

Answer (score 1):

Слова «будто», «как», «словно» являются союзами, когда связывают однородные члены или предложения. В данном случае ничего подобного они не связывают. В такого рода примерах эти слова обозначают отношения глагола и существительного и являются предлогами.